# How to integrate $4xe^{-2x}$

Tags: calculus, integration

As the question said how do I even begin to integrate it? I did it before but after a long time I kinda forgot about it. I'm confused as can I integrate both $x$ and $e^{-2x}$ seperately or do I need to do something first?

Comment: Integration by parts.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Thanks! But is there any other methods? or is this the only one.

Comment: There's probably a dozen other methods, but parts is the simplest and most obvious one, and what the vast majority of people would attack it with. Integrals like this are kind of integral that integration by parts looks like it was created for

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Alright because in my class it seems like my teacher avoid the question with xe on it and do the question only with e alone so when it's near exam I found this question in the exercise and I'm kinda confused.

Comment: Maybe you didn't learn integration by parts yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's integrate by parts:
Note that $$\frac{de^{-2x}}{dx}=-2e^{-2x}\Rightarrow dx=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{d(e^{-2x})}{e^{-2x}}$$ This contributes to:
$$\int xe^{-2x}dx=-\frac{1}{2}\int xe^{-2x}\frac{d(e^{-2x})}{e^{-2x}}=-\frac{1}{2}\int xd(e^{-2x})$$
Integration by parts pattern is:
$$\int udv=uv-\int vdu$$
We have $u=x, v=e^{-2x}$:
$$I=-\frac{1}{2}\Big(xe^{-2x}-\int e^{-2x}dx\Big)=-\frac{1}{2}xe^{-2x}+\frac{1}{2}\int e^{-2x}dx=-\frac{1}{2}xe^{-2x}-\frac{1}{4}e^{-2x}$$

Helpful theory on how to use integration by parts and other techniques is in [this resource](http://alints.com/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try integration by parts where $4x$ is differentiated and $e^{-2x}$ is integrated.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
 \int 4 x e^{-2 x} d x 
= & -2 \int x d\left(e^{-2 x}\right) \\
= & -2 x e^{-2 x}+2 \int e^{-2 x} d x \\
= & -2 x e^{-2 x}-e^{-2 x}+C
\end{aligned}
$$